# Spell Check window using MSWord interop opening in back of my application in Vista

Tags: c#, winforms, interop, ms-word, spell-checking

I'm using `MSWord` interop to check grammar/spell in my application. I'm using these steps to do this:

1. Create a new Single Thread Apartment to not lock my application's form
2. Disable the input of my application
3. Using reflection (to be `MSOffice` version independent)

I'm using this code to open Word:

```
objWord = System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application"));
Object objDocuments = objWord.GetType().InvokeMember("Documents", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, objWord, null);
objDoc = objDocuments.GetType().InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objDocuments, null);
objContent = objDoc.GetType().InvokeMember("Content", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, objDoc, null);

IDataObject oldObjData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(text);

objContent.GetType().InvokeMember("Paste", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objContent, null);

objDoc.GetType().GetMethod("CheckGrammar").Invoke(objDoc, null);
objWord.GetType().GetProperty("Visible").SetValue(objWord, false, null);
objContent.GetType().InvokeMember("Cut", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objContent, null);

IDataObject objData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

objDoc.GetType().GetProperty("Saved").SetValue(objDoc, true, null);
objDoc.GetType().GetMethod("Close").Invoke(objDoc, new Object[] { null, null, null });
objWord.GetType().GetMethod("Quit").Invoke(objWord, new Object[] { null, null, null });
```

But when I call this, only in Windows Vista, the SpellCheck window opens in the back of my application, and I need to use **ALT+TAB** to show the Word's window.

Anybody had this problem or have a suggestion how to solve?

I tried to call

```
objDoc.GetType().GetMethod("Activate").Invoke(objDoc, null);
```

but it doesn't work. Other "Focus" methods neither.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Activate` on Word's `Application` object.  (Not the `Document` object)

**EDIT**: Try calling it before displaying the spell-check dialog.

Comment: I tried in both already, both, Focus and Activate.
But thanks anyway.

Comment: I tried everything with Focus and Activate in every plausible position with no success.